# How do i add same string to a ListBox in some lines?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

In the top of the Form i have:

```
string[] data;
Color []color;
```

In the constructor:

```
color = new Color[1] { Color.Red};
```

Then i have a function i load in the constructor:

```
private void ListBoxLoadKeys(Dictionary<string,List<string>> dictionary, 
    string FileName)
{
    string line = System.String.Empty;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(keywords))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            int i = line.Count();
            tokens = line.Split(',');
            dictionary.Add(tokens[0], tokens.Skip(1).ToList());
            // listBox1.Items.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " 
                + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);     
            data = new string[1] { "Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " 
                + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]};
            listBox1.DataSource = data;
        }           
    }        
}
```

But its adding to the ListBox only once one lines.
I want it to be like listbox1.Items.Add then its adding all the lines from the text file to the listBox.

Then im coloring the lines in Red:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(data[e.Index], new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8,
        FontStyle.Regular),new SolidBrush(color[e.Index]), e.Bounds);
}

private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = 16;
}
```

1. how can i add all the lines from the StreamReader instead using Items.Add but using DataSource ?
2. How can i color in Red only the word "Url: " i have this line:

   > data = new string[1] { "Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]};

And i want it to add all the lines from the text file and each line to color only the word "Url: "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should read all the lines and fill data and then bind it to the ListBox control. I suggest List rather than Array because you don't know how many lines in text you will have. Here is the code for that:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
private void ListBoxLoadKeys(Dictionary<string,List<string>> dictionary, string FileName)
        {

               string line = System.String.Empty;

               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(keywords))
               {
                   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                       int i = line.Count();
                       tokens = line.Split(',');
                       dictionary.Add(tokens[0], tokens.Skip(1).ToList());
                      // listBox1.Items.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);
                       data.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);

                   }
               }
               listBox1.DataSource = data;
}
```

For the other part of the question, since you are always drawing the same word "Url:", than you can change your code this way:

**EDIT:** This is the best I could get in a short time. I hope this is what you are looking for. Remember that drawing controls yourself is a tricky business and that you need to have a lot of experience with both WinForms and GDI+. From your posts I could conclude that you are a beginner so watch out, there is a lot to learn. I made a double buffered drawing of the items so you will not experience any flickering and the items wont get **bolder** with new redraws. Nevertheless this is not optimal code but it will do the trick for your purpose. In case you need to draw selected items in the listbox, I advise you to check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawitemstate.aspx). In that case, depending on the state, you could `Clear` the bitmap with different colors, hence change the background color of the item.

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index >= 0 && e.Index < data.Count)
        {
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.Clear(listView1.BackColor);
            string url = data[e.Index].Substring(0, 4);
            Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(url, f);
            RectangleF urlRectF = new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, 0, size.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
            g.DrawString(url, f, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), urlRectF); 
            RectangleF restRectF = new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + size.Width, 0, e.Bounds.Width - size.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
            g.DrawString(data[e.Index].Substring(4), f, new SolidBrush(Color.Green), restRectF);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp,e.Bounds);
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nick tried your code no exceptions but i dontt see anything in the listBox.

Comment: Nick no i dont see anything the listBox1 is empty.

Comment: Nick but using breakpoint i see that data contain 6 items and also after listBox1.DataSource = data; i see that listBox1 and DataSource contain 6 items too.

Comment: Nick ok removed it outside the function added it in the top of the Form. Now i see in the listBox1 one Url: in red but thats it i dont see the rest of the line: data.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]); i dont see the tokens[0] the --- the localy keyword: and not the tokens[1] another thing i see only one Url: while data contain 6 items.

Comment: Nick now i see all the lines after changed the DrawItem event code to yours but its coloring all the lines to Red and not only the "Url: " ( including one space Url: ) Btw: I want to color when it will work also the end of each line wich is tokens[1]

Comment: @user1741587 I'll look into it later. I'm writing from the phone atm. The colors are the problem. The problem is that you have only one color in the array but e.Index might be greater than 0 therefore producing index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

Set the data source outside of the while loop.  Or add items to the listbox like this

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);
```

Comment: Mark i used a breakpoint on the line listBox1.DataSource = data; and saw that data contain 6 items and when moving forward i saw that listBox1.Source contain also 6 items so i guess the problem maybe in the DrawItem event ?